# When load SavedModel in TF2, reportes "signature_wrapper takes 0 positional arguments but 1 were given"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I try to create a decoder, which takes five-Tensor tuple as input. As I saved it as `.h5` it works fine, but as I try to save(no error report), load, and do inference, it reports:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/MA/Recources/monodepth2-torch/dsy.py", line 196, in <module>
    build_model(inputs)
  File "D:/MA/Recources/monodepth2-torch/dsy.py", line 185, in build_model
    outputs = decoder_pb(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\Dexxh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1655, in __call__
    return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dexxh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1673, in _call_impl
    return self._call_with_flat_signature(args, kwargs, cancellation_manager)
  File "C:\Users\Dexxh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1695, in _call_with_flat_signature
    len(args)))
TypeError: signature_wrapper(input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4, input_5) takes 0 positional arguments but 1 were given
```

My definition of the Model is as follows. The details seem no problem, because it runs fine when I load it as Keras model. And I use `tensorflow 2.3.1` in case you need.

```
class DepthDecoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DepthDecoder, self).__init__()
        self.num_ch_enc = [64, 64, 128, 256, 512]
        self.num_ch_dec = [16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
        self.scales = [0,1,2,3]  # range(4)
        self.num_output_channels = 1

        self.convs_0 = [None]*len(self.num_ch_dec)
        self.convs_1 = [None]*len(self.num_ch_dec)

        # todo: dispconv can be multiple output
        self.dispconv_0 = self.make_conv(self.num_ch_dec[0], self.num_output_channels, activate_type=None,
                                         pad_mode='reflect', type='disp', index=0)

        for i in range(4, -1, -1):
            # upconv_0
            num_ch_in = self.num_ch_enc[-1] if i == 4 else self.num_ch_dec[i + 1]
            num_ch_out = self.num_ch_dec[i]
            self.convs_0[i] = self.make_conv(num_ch_in, num_ch_out, pad_mode='reflect', activate_type='elu',
                                             type='conv_0', index=i)

            # upconv_1
            num_ch_in = self.num_ch_dec[i]
            if i > 0:
                num_ch_in += self.num_ch_enc[i - 1]
            num_ch_out = self.num_ch_dec[i]
            self.convs_1[i] = self.make_conv(num_ch_in, num_ch_out, pad_mode='reflect', activate_type='elu',
                                             type='conv_1', index=i)



    def make_conv(self, input_channel, filter_num, activate_type=None, pad_mode='reflect',
                  type:str=None, index=-1, input_shape:tuple=None):
        name = None
        if type is not None and index != -1:
            name = ''.join([type, '_%d'%index])
        if pad_mode == 'reflect':
            padding = 'valid'
        else:
            padding = 'same'
        conv = Conv2D(filters=filter_num, kernel_size=3, activation=activate_type,
                      strides=1, padding=padding, use_bias=True, name=name)
        return conv


    def call(self, input_features, training=None, mask=None):
        ch_axis = 3
        x = input_features[-1]
        for i in range(4, -1, -1):
            x = tf.pad(x, [[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0]], mode='REFLECT')
            x = self.convs_0[i](x)
            x = [tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D()(x)]
            if i > 0:
                x += [input_features[i - 1]]
            x = tf.concat(x, ch_axis)
            x = tf.pad(x, [[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0]], mode='REFLECT')
            x = self.convs_1[i](x)
                # outputs.append(tf.math.sigmoid(x))
        x = tf.pad(x, [[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0]], mode='REFLECT')
        x = self.dispconv_0(x)
        disp0 = tf.math.sigmoid(x)

        return disp0
```

Then save and load:

```
inputs = (tf.random.uniform(shape=(1,96, 320, 64)),
          tf.random.uniform(shape=(1,48, 160, 64)),
          tf.random.uniform(shape=(1,24, 80, 128)),
          tf.random.uniform(shape=(1,12, 40, 256)),
          tf.random.uniform(shape=(1,6, 20, 512)))
# Load
decoder = DepthDecoder()
outputs = decoder.predict(inputs)
decoder = decoder_load_weights(decoder) # a custom weights loading from Pytorch, weights, details see below
tf.keras.models.save_model(decoder, "decoder_test")

# Inference
decoder_import = tf.saved_model.load("decoder_test")
decoder_pb = decoder_import.signatures['serving_default']
outputs = decoder_pb(inputs)
for k, v in outputs:
   print(v.shape)

# For completeness, here is the decoder_load_weigths() function
def decoder_load_weights(decoder, weights_path=None):
    # Weights as List of ndarray, stored layerwise. Since it's fully convolutional, it's like [[#conv_0]*5,[#conv1]*5, [dispconv]], nothing else.
    decoder_weights = np.load(weights_path, allow_pickle=True)
    ind = 0
    for l in decoder.layers:
        print(l.name)
        weights = l.get_weights()
        if len(weights) == 0:
            print("no weigths")
        else:
            print(weights[0].shape, "\t", weights[1].shape)
            print(weights_grouped[ind][0].shape, "\t", weights_grouped[ind][1].shape)
            new_weights = weights_grouped[ind]
            l.set_weights(new_weights)
            print("loading the %dnd conv layer..."% ind)
            ind += 1
    return decoder
```

It's weird that it says takes **0** positional argument, suggesting no inputs allowed. Could you offer any insights? Thanks!!

At last, let me post a snapshot of what's inside of `decoder_pb` (called `infer` in the snapshot). You can see that the `decoder_pb` indeed already has `Tensor` named *input_1*, *input_2* and so on, so the question is how can I **assign my inputs to them**.
I cannot directly assign Tensors to them, because the "name" of the assigned Tensor is not `input_1` and **EagerTensor cannot be renamed**.

I remember in TF1.x there's  `feed_dict` passed in `session`, don't know if  it's related...
[image]

Comment: Where is `decoder_load_weights` defined?

Comment: @M.Innat I have added the definition. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Solved!

It turns out to be exactly what the error report means... it takes no *positional* argument, meaning it only takes *keyword* arguments. So the solution can be

```
res = infer(input_1=features[0], input_2=features[1], ...)
```

or

```
# feed_dict = {'input_1' : features[0], ...}
res = infer(**feed_dict)
```

but this is not accepted:

```
disp_raw = decoder(features[0], features[1],features[2],features[3], features[4])
```

It's actually strange, because normally we don't need to specify the keywords, as long as we are passing them in the right order. Also, we don't need this when we only have one single input, e.g. `res = infer(#one_tensor)`.

So I guess it's kind of a bug? Yeah anyway, hope others who encounter this problem could benefit from this answer :)

Comment: Thanks. Stumbled across this after changing the model architecture from 1 to 2 inputs